# How could you stretch a face image to simulate added weight?

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-image, cifilter

I am attempting to simulate adding weight to a person's face by taking a still `UIImage` and applying some effect that widens the cheeks/jawline areas, without affecting the rest of the face. I have tried various approaches but haven't been successful. How could this be accomplished, without using an OpenGL map?

I am already using facial feature detection to detect where the eyes are and the face bounds.

I've tried using the `CIPinchDistortion` filter, placing one on both sides of the face, and this does cause the face to look fatter but this pinches the entire image and stretches out the face vertically.

I've tried cropping out just the face and applying the `CIPinchDistortion` then placing that image back on top of the original, but this causes it to not line up on the photo.

I've tried using the third-party `GPUImage` filter `GPUImageBulgeDistortionFilter` but this expands everything out from the center point, therefore pushing the lips together when this effect is placed on both sides of the face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend adding a couple strategically placed CIBumpDistortions.  For an example see the "Chipmunk" effect in the OS X version of Photo Booth.

Comment: `CIBumpDistortion` is not available on iOS, only OS X.

Comment: There could an error in the docs.  I should be in iOS 6 and later.  Try calling [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBumpDistortion"] and see if it returns non-nil.

Comment: It does return non-nil. Interesting, I'll give it a shot.